# How can I get ConEmu, Far Manager and the VS Developer Command Prompt to play nice together?

Tags: windows, command-line, visual-studio, conemu, far-manager

I'm currently trying to set up my environment such that I can open a ConEmu tab and it will automatically initialize Far Manager and the VS Developer Command Prompt environment.

My failed attempt was this:

```
cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64_x86 & far -new_console:d:C:\My\Code
```

This works in that it accomplishes what I want, but ConEmu doesn't like it because it leaves an active cmd.exe instance, so when you try to close the tab you will always get a warning, which is not ideal.

If you've never seen this before, this is what pops up on tab closure if you use the above task:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/o0GyS5I.png]

After a whole bunch of searching I found this link which contains a comment at the bottom by the ConEmu author:

http://www.gurustop.net/blog/2014/02/01/using-visual-studio-developer-command-prompt-with-powershell/

He says this:

> Yep, that is working. But this method left cmd.exe in your working process tree.
>
> Another way - run vcvarsall.bat from you shell (PowerShell or Far Manager) and export changed environment from cmd to the parent process. The advantage - you can set up different settings at run time.
>
> Description: https://code.google.com/p/cone...
>
> And example command (I'm using that from Far Manager):
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 & "%ConEmuBaseDir%\ConEmuC.exe" /export=CON

The problem with this however is that I have to run this command manually after running far. I can't seem to find a way to automatically run that command after initializing Far.

It's not really a viable solution to do it manually because I have so many different environments to set up. Consider that I want a different tab for each compiler I'm using (MSVC, Clang, GCC, Intel C++ - sometimes multiple version of each, and pretty much always multiple architectures).

Basically I need a way to set up a task such that I can either run a batch file, followed by Far (so it inherits the env vars) without leaving a dangling cmd.exe instance. Or, I need to be able to set up a task such that I can automatically run a command (different per task) after running Far.

I'm pretty sure there would be some black magic way to do it, but I'm not familiar enough with ConEmu/Far yet to figure it out.

If I get super desperate I'll probably end up writing a plugin, but I'd rather avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ConEmu has *[forking](http://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuC.html#Commands)* abitily. So, you may just call

   ```
   -new_console:d:C:\My\Code cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64_x86 & ConEmuC -fork -c far"
   ```
2. Far Manager has its own Macro system. You may either set up "Auto started" macro, or just pass it via command line. Consider proper quotation! Just change `F2 F1` to your keys sequence. Easies way is adding required command to the F2 (User Menu).

   ```
   -new_console:d:C:\My\Code cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64_x86 & far "lua:Keys(\"F2 F1\")""
   ```

Comment: Running the first command appears to break Far for me. For example, instead of Ctrl+O toggling the view I just get "^O" at the prompt. (It also continues to suffer from the same problem of causing a prompt when closing the tab, but I'm assuming that's related to the first issue.)

Comment: Not `/k` but `/c`!

Comment: That causes the tab to stay open with an error message on close, but at least there is no popup so I can probably live with that. :)

"ConEmuC: Root process was alive less than 10 sec, ExitCode=x00000103(259).
Press Enter or Esc to close console..."

Thanks so much for your awesome project.

Comment: Another documented switch: `-new_console:n`

Answer (score 0):

I made this by combining two predefined monstrous commands for {Far} and for {SDK::VS 15.0 x64 tools prompt} using `&&`:

```
-new_console:t:"VS 15.0" -new_console:C:"%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VSFileHandler.dll,38" cmd /c ""%ConEmuDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64 && set "FARHOME=" & "%ConEmuDir%\..\Far Manager\far.exe" /w /p"%ConEmuDir%\Plugins\ConEmu;%FARHOME%\Plugins;%FARPROFILE%\Plugins""
```

[image: Settings screenshot]